# True color support in TTY

Tags: terminal, tty, colors

I'd like to know if there's any way to get true color support in the tty. To be clear, I don't mean a terminal emulator, I mean the actual tty you get when no display server is running.

Answer (score 2):

[The Linux console](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) supports ECMA-48 SGR codes, including 24-bit RGB colour specifiers:

```
for (( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )); do
    printf '\e[38;2;0;0;%dma\e[0m' "$i"
done
printf '\n'
```

However the current implementation collapses this down to the closest of the sixteen colours in the default palette, even if the console is using a framebuffer.

The framebuffer itself in Linux does support 24-bit colour, so it would be possible to write a console terminal emulator (such as [FbTerm](https://github.com/sfzhi/fbterm)) with full support for 24-bit SGR codes, but I’m not aware of one currently.

Tools such as [`fbi`](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida/) can be used to display true-colour images on the console. The `fbida` source tarballs include `fbcon` which supports 256-colour SGR codes:

```
for (( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )); do
    printf '\e[38;5;%dma\e[0m' "$i"
done
printf '\n'
```

[image: Screenshot of fbcon displaying 256 colours]

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to write true-color terminal emulator. You are mixing logical screen with hardware one.

Comment: No, I’m not talking about a framebuffer as an abstraction for a drawing surface; I’m talking about a framebuffer in the `fbdev` or KMS sense.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The actual terminal is running in ["text mode" of the video card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode). There are several text modes. And by historical reasons the maximum coloring is 16 colors. Some time, long ago the text mode stopped improving, in favor of graphical ones.

So it is theoretically possible to have a 24bit colors (true color) in the text mode, but you would have to find a very unusual hardware for that.

Comment: “Very unusual hardware” — not really, the vast majority of Linux systems use a framebuffer nowadays.

Comment: Do not mistake framebuffer for actual screen.

Comment: I’m not; I’m talking about the framebuffer used on platforms without PC-style text modes, or on PCs, the framebuffer set up for the console when using KMS.